# PHP How to get an input values type through $_POST

Tags: php, forms, variables, post, types

Hi I am sending a form through post to a php file that I have made. I have been able to use $_POST["name"] to get the vales of input fields of type text/password,/etc but now I would like to also get their 'type'. So in my variable $car = $_POST["car"]; will store the value, I would like $carInputType to store the inputs type. So if in the form the person chose Mazda in a checkbox, I would like the $carInputType to hold 'checkbox' the type.

I hope I explained this well I think this could be useful for many people to learn. I have been looking around but I have not found ANYTHING to answer this. I have tried:

```
$radio = $_POST["fname[type]"];
$radio = $_POST["fname[type=]"];
```

A bit of my form is as follows:

```
<form id="ajax-form" onsubmit="return false;">
<div><label for="uname">Username <em>*</em></label> <input id="uname"     type="text" name="uname" value=""  /><p class='note' id = "userNameID"></p>        </div>
</form>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reviewing my post.

Comment: what is form html code?

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: It is though, I posted my form to my php page and can easily grab the value of it using $name = $_POST["uname"];  Now I would just like to store the type not the value

Comment: The <form> sets type ... method="get" or method="post". If you are confused set a hidden input and check if(isset($_GET['hidden)) {... or if(isset($_POST['hidden)) {

Comment: That is not what I mean at all..please read the entire post, it is fairly straight forward what I am trying to do, I gave examples

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with only PHP. You would use JavaScript or jquery to build the post data as you need it.

```
var data =    $('#myForm').serializeArray();    
data.push({
    name: 'elementName', 
    value: 'elementValue',
    Type: 'element type'
}); 
$.post("page.php", data);
```

Comment: If I can get the value easily through post I do not see why I cannot get the type

Comment: Because post transmits only the name value pairs, not the element type. If you look at the post data the type is not sent. See the following W3 spec. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.3.